# Showing the normality of topological space

Tags: general-topology, continuity, separation-axioms

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T})$ be a map defined by $f(x)=x$ if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, $f(x)=0$ if $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, where $\mathcal{T}$ is the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Now, suppose that the domain $\mathbb{R}$ is equipped the following topology: $$\mathcal{T}_{w}=\left\{f^{-1}(U)\,:\,U\in\mathcal{T}\right\}.$$
Then, clearly, $f$ is a continuous map.

Is it possible to show the normality of the space $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T}_{w})$ using the fact that the continuity of $f$ and the normality of $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T})$?

I tried to prove it by definition, but there was no progress.

Can anyone help me? or give some advice? Thank you!

Comment: If $x,y \in \Bbb R$ are irrational they're in the same open sets of $\mathcal{T}_w$. So the space is almost indiscrete. I do hope your definition of normal does not include $T_1$-ness or you're doomed.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, yes, sir. It does not include $T_{1}$-assumption. By the way, I found that the space $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T}_{w})$ is both regular and second countable. It is easier than showing the space is normal by definition only. However, i still wonder that 'is there an another way to show that the space is normal using some properties of continuity of $f$ or weak topology?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be re-written as follows: let $F_1,F_2$ be two closed (for the usual topology) subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, such that $F_1 \cap F_2$ has no rational point. Show that there are open subsets $U_i$ such that $U_i \supset F_i \cap \mathbb{Q}$ and $U_1 \cap U_2$ has no rational point, ie $U_1$ and $U_2$ are disjoint.

You can just define, if $i$ is $1$ or $2$, $$U_i=\bigcup_{x \in F_i \cap \mathbb{Q}}{\left(x-\frac{d(x,F_{3-i})}{5},x+\frac{d(x,F_{3-i})}{5}\right)}.$$

Comment: $U_1 \cap U_2$ having no rational point is just claiming these sets are disjoint.

Comment: You are right, I edited my answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Mindlack Thanks for comment!